# Extract desired text from a field

Tags: formula-field, administration

In my org there is a record on a custom object which on creation populates a URL on a path field : /lightning/r/Account/0012w000019tsbCAAQ/edit

From the above mentioned URL I need the record Id to store it in a separate field. I have tried using formula field to retrieve the record Id but not sure what to do when the object name in the url is dynamic

Formula field which I created:

```
LEFT(RIGHT(Path__c, LEN(Path__c) - 21),18)
```

This removes '/lightning/r/Account/' & 'edit' but how can I make the formula dynamic depending on the type of object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUBSTITUTE to get rid of constant `/edit`, then take rightmost 18 chars

```
 RIGHT(
       SUBSTITUTE(Path__c,'/edit',NULL),
       18)
```